# How to save generated QR code into gallery directly (not with SD card and not under package name)

Tags: android, qr-code

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
    if (pictureFile == null) {
       // Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       // Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
       // Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have used above code to save generated QR in Gallery. and it is working too.

But it is saving in `Internal Storage/package_name/Files/mtImage.jpg`.

I have to go to file manager in order to view it. I want to view it directly in Gallery and I don't have any SD card.

Please help me with this.

Comment: You need to notify the system about that you have created a new image there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369887/how-can-i-notify-the-gallery-of-a-new-image-in-android

Comment: Internal storage it's only project directory, not sd card. Path to that is `/data/data/<your_package_name>/files/`

Comment: Can anyone post the code to save generated Qr code into Gallery?  Whatever the code i have used above is for Sd card but i dont want that

Comment: Yes..Vladyslav Matviienko answer worked...but before that some tricks we have to do

Answer (score 0):

Below code helps to save bitmap image to gallery

public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

    context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```